# Lifting of arbitrary map to a covering space

Tags: covering-spaces, fundamental-groups, continuous-homomorphisms

> Let $(\tilde{X},p)$ be a covering space of $X$, $\tilde{x}_{0}\in\tilde{X}$, $x_{0}=p(\tilde{x}_{0})$, $y_{0}\in Y$ and $\varphi :(Y,y_{0})\rightarrow (X,x_{0})$. Under what conditions does there exist a map $\tilde{\varphi}:(Y,y_{0})\rightarrow (\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_{0})$ such that the diagram [image: the diagram] is commutative? If we assume such a map $\tilde{\varphi}$ exists, we obtain the follow commutative diagram of groups and homomorphisms:[image: Second diagram] **beacuse $p_{*}$ is a monomorphism** the existence of a homomorphism $\tilde{\varphi}_{*}:\pi(Y,y_{0})\rightarrow\pi(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_{0})$ which makes the diagram commutative, is exactly equivalent to the dondition that the image $\varphi{*}$ be contained in the image of $p_{*}$

The Massey says this before the theroem of the lifting of an arbitrary map. But I don't see where we use the fact that $p_{*}$ is a monomorphism. In general, if $$(p_{*}\circ\tilde{\varphi})=\varphi$$ the condition on the images is tha same without assumptions on $p_{*}$...
If I know that there is that commutative diagram, my necessary condition is image of $\varphi_{*}$ in image of $p_{*}$. I don't need the fact that $p_{*}$ is a monomorphism. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Given $\varphi_*$ and $p_*$, there may be no $\tilde{\varphi}_*$ such that $(p_* \circ \tilde{\varphi}_*) = \varphi_*$.
It is the *existence* of such a $\tilde{\varphi}_*$ that is dependent on the condition that the image of $\varphi_*$ is contained in the image of $p_*$.

Comment: Yes, this is a necessary condition

Comment: But I see that the Massey says "Because p_* is a monomorphism" wher I use the fact that p_{*} is a monomorphism?

Comment: You use it to construct $\tilde{\varphi}_*$. To see that some condition is necessary, let $p : \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ be the natural projection and let $\varphi: \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ be the identity homomorphism: there is no $\tilde{\varphi}: \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}$ such that $p \circ \tilde{\varphi} = \varphi$.

Comment: Why? If I define $\tilde{\varphi}([0])=0$ and $\tilde{\varphi}([1]) = 1$ where [0], [1] are the equivalence classes, it doesn't work?

Comment: Your $\tilde{\phi}$ isn't a group homomorphism.

Comment: Because $\tilde{\varphi}([1]+[1])=0\neq \tilde{\varphi}([1])+\tilde{\varphi}([1])=2$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.